# JQuery + MouseOver Reset FadeOut

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that shows a drop down box which fades out and is then removed:

```
$('.containerDIV').show().fadeOut(10000, function() {$(this).remove();});
```

The above code works well but I want to update it so if a user puts a mouse over `$('.containerDIV')` the fade out stops and when the mouse moves out it starts again.

Hoping someone could give me a push in the right direction.

Comment: I think you'd have to write your own fadeOut to support that.  you could probably just copy the jquery method, and add an event hook to pause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use [`.stop(true, false)`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/), which will halt any current animation and clear the animation queue. Then you can use [`fadeIn(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) to show the div again instantly.

```js
// Cache DIVs
var $containerDIVs = $('.containerDIV');

// Start Initial Fade
FadeAndRemove($containerDIVs);

// On mouseover, stop fade and show again
$containerDIVs.on("mouseover", function(e) {
  $(this).stop(true /*, false implied */ ).fadeIn(0);
});

// On mouse leave, start fade again
$containerDIVs.on("mouseleave", function(e) {
  FadeAndRemove(this);
});

// Fading function
function FadeAndRemove(els) {
  $(els).fadeOut(10000, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containerDIV">
  testing 123
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0oh0v96j/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery .stop() command will interrupt any current animation, toggle, or fade in it's current position.

Have a look at this example of stop(), and also chaining multiple events to the same function.

```
function fadeHandler(e){
    $(this).fadeOut(5000, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    })
}

$('.containerDIV').show(fadeHandler).mouseout(fadeHandler)
$('.containerDIV').mouseover(function(){$(this).stop()})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0j680L1t/